# Symfony Test - null token with Guard Authentication

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I have a Guard Authentication in my Symfony Web Application. I would like to perform some unit tests. I'm unable to simulate an authentification in my tests. The token stays `null` when calling `$tokenStorage->getToken()`.

**Note:**

- The login authentification is working under `dev` and `prod` environnement.
- I saw quite a lot of related topics without success and the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/testing/http_authentication.html).
- Symfony version: 3.4.

**Reproduce**: you can reproduce the error from this [repo](https://github.com/alexandreb09/SO_Reproduce) (symfony project). This repo defined one entity [`User`](https://github.com/alexandreb09/SO_Reproduce/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php) with a custom constraint validator [`ExampleValidator`](https://github.com/alexandreb09/SO_Reproduce/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Validator/ExampleValidator.php). In this constraint, I need to have the current logged user.

**Code sample:**

After manually creating an User, the `login` function used in tests:

```php
private function logIn($firewallName = 'main'){
   // dummy call to bypass the hasPreviousSession check
   $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
   $session = $this->client->getContainer()->get('session');

   /** @var User $user */
   $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)
       ->findOneBy(['email' => 'user1@example.com']);

   // you may need to use a different token class depending on your application.
   // for example, when using Guard authentication you must instantiate PostAuthenticationGuardToken
   $token = new PostAuthenticationGuardToken($user, $firewallName, [new Role('ROLE_CLIENT')]);
        self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

   $session->set('_security_'.$firewallName, serialize($token));
   $session->save();

   $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
   $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
}
```

The User call from `tokenStorage` (from service function):

```
class ExampleValidator extends ConstraintValidator{
    protected $requestStack;
    protected $em;
    protected $user_id;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $request,
                                EntityManager $em,
                                TokenStorage $tokenStorage){
        $this->requestStack = $request;
        $this->em = $em;

        /** @var User $user */
        // Token is always null
        $user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $this->user_id = $user != "anon." ? $user->getId() : null;
    }

    /**
     * @param $value
     * @param Constraint $constraint
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        // validation rules ...
    }
}
```

`LoginFormAuthenticator.php`

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security;


use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;
    private $loginAttemptRepository;


    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
                                UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator,
                                CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager,
                                UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder){
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supports(Request $request){
        return $request->getPathInfo() == '/login_check' &&
            $request->isMethod('POST') &&
            $request->request->get('_password') !== null;
    }


    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array|mixed|void|null
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request){
        $isLoginSubmit = $request->getPathInfo() == '/login_check' &&
            $request->isMethod('POST') &&
            $request->request->get('_password') !== null;
        $isCaptcha = $request->request->get('captcha_set');

        if ($isCaptcha == 1 && $request->request->get('_password') !== null) {
            $secret = ...;
            if($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] !== null){
                // Paramètre renvoyé par le recaptcha
                $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
                $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

                $api_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret="
                    . $secret
                    . "&response=" . $response
                    . "&remoteip=" . $remoteip ;

                $decode = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url), true);

                if ($decode['success'] == true) {
                    $username = $request->request->get('_username');
                    $password = $request->request->get('_password');
                    $csrfToken = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');

                    if (false === $this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid(new CsrfToken('authenticate', $csrfToken))) {
                        throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException('Invalid CSRF token.');
                    }

                    $request->getSession()->set(
                        Security::LAST_USERNAME,
                        $username
                    );

                    return [
                        'username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password,
                    ];
                }
                else{
                    throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Captcha invalids.');
                }
            }
            else{
                throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Captcha invalids.');
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!$isLoginSubmit) {
                // skip authentication
                return;
            }

            $username = $request->request->get('_username');
            $password = $request->request->get('_password');
            $csrfToken = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');

            if (false === $this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid(new CsrfToken('authenticate', $csrfToken))) {
                throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException('Invalid CSRF token.');
            }

            $request->getSession()->set(
                Security::LAST_USERNAME,
                $username
            );

            return [
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
            ];
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     * @return User|object|UserInterface|null
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider){
        $username = $credentials["username"];
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);
        return $user;
    }


    /**
     * @param mixed $credentials
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user){
        $password = $credentials["password"];
        $rep = false;
        if ($this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $password)){
            $rep = true;
        }
        return $rep;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @param string $providerKey
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey){
        $targetPath = null;
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('map'));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getLoginUrl(){
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('fos_user_security_login');
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `ExampleValidator` doing in there? How is it relevant?

Comment: @yivi This isn't relevant here. I defined the validator [`ExampleValidator`](https://github.com/alexandreb09/SO_Reproduce/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Validator/ExampleValidator.php) as an example constraint for the [`User`](https://github.com/alexandreb09/SO_Reproduce/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php) class. I have an entity with custom constraints I want to test. On some of these constraints, I need to have the current logged user.

Comment: If it's not relevant here, remove it. It induces to confusion. Leave only what's relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: Hum, I'm sorry not to be clear. The `ExampleValidator` is actually the problem, I mean the content of the above "reproductible" example isn't relevant. It's only a dummy example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the root of your problem is that you are using multiple container instances. In particular, your `logIn()` function works on the container of the client, but the validator is from a different container that you boot up during `setUp()`. Thus, the changes you make in `logIn()` to the client container do not affect the validator you are actually testing.

Using the same container everywhere, e.g. the one from the client, should solve this. The following changes to your repository make the test pass:

```
diff --git a/tests/AppBundle/Validator/UserTest.php b/tests/AppBundle/Validator/UserTest.php
index f15c854..603e566 100644
--- a/tests/AppBundle/Validator/UserTest.php
+++ b/tests/AppBundle/Validator/UserTest.php
@@ -44,10 +44,7 @@ class UserTest extends WebTestCase{
         $this->container = $this->client->getContainer();
         $this->entityManager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

-        // Set validator
-        $kernel = $this->createKernel();
-        $kernel->boot();
-        $this->validator = $kernel->getContainer()->get('validator');
+        $this->validator = $this->client->getContainer()->get('validator');

         // Create one user
         $this->createOneUser();
@@ -100,7 +97,7 @@ class UserTest extends WebTestCase{
         // you may need to use a different token class depending on your application.
         // for example, when using Guard authentication you must instantiate PostAuthenticationGuardToken
         $token = new PostAuthenticationGuardToken($user, $firewallName, [new Role('ROLE_CLIENT')]);
-        self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
+        $this->client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

         $session->set('_security_'.$firewallName, serialize($token));
         $session->save();
```